# Need list of customers with 2 addresses in the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to extract all my customer info from the db. Part of this result set will be address columns.

I have a user table and address table. The address table holds 0-many addresses for each user. I only need the last 2 that were created for each user.

So far I have this query which returns all customer data, joined with the region table to get the currency name, and left joined with orders to get total number of shipped orders for that user.

```
SELECT ( CASE
           WHEN u.password IS NULL THEN 'GUEST'
           ELSE 'CUSTOMER'
         END )                                 AS STATUS,
       u.date_created                          AS DateCreated,
       u.NAME                                  AS UserName,
       u.password                              AS Password,
       u.email                                 AS Email,
       r.token                                 AS Currency,
       Cast(u.balance / 100 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS Balance,
       Count(o.user_id)                        AS TotalShippedOrders
FROM   [db].[user] u
       INNER JOIN [db].[region] r
               ON r.currency_id = u.balance_currency
       LEFT JOIN [db].[order] o
              ON o.user_id = u.id
                 AND o.status = 'shipped'
GROUP  BY u.id,
          u.date_created,
          u.NAME,
          u.password,
          u.email,
          r.token,
          u.balance
ORDER  BY TotalShippedOrders DESC;
```

The `address` table has `user_id, address, city, state, etc, date_created` columns.

I have no idea how to join the address table to my above query to only get the **last 2 addresses** on the same row. I would like to add the following columns to my original query:

```
address1, city1, state1, address2, city2, state2
```

and only populate those with the **last 2 addresses** for that user.

Can someone point me in a direction on how to formulate this part of my query? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `pivot` the `address` table data before joining with the `user` table

```
;WITH address_cte -- Generate ROW_NUMBER to find the last two address for each user_id
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY user_id
                    ORDER BY date_created DESC) AS rn,
                user_id,
                address,
                city,
                state
         FROM   address),
     address_pivot -- Pivot the address
     AS (SELECT user_id,
                Max(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN address END) AS address_1,
                Max(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN city END) AS city_1,
                Max(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN state END) AS state_1,
                Max(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN address END) AS address_2,
                Max(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN city END) AS city_2,
                Max(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN state END) AS state_2,
                COUNT(1) as Address_count
         FROM   address_cte
         GROUP  BY user_id)
SELECT ( CASE
           WHEN u.password IS NULL THEN 'GUEST'
           ELSE 'CUSTOMER'
         END )                                 AS STATUS,
       u.date_created                          AS DateCreated,
       u.NAME                                  AS UserName,
       u.password                              AS Password,
       u.email                                 AS Email,
       r.token                                 AS Currency,
       Cast(u.balance / 100 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS Balance,
       Count(o.user_id)                        AS TotalShippedOrders,
       address_1,
       city_1,
       state_1,
       address_2,
       city_2,
       state_2,
       Address_count
FROM   [db].[user] u
       INNER JOIN [db].[region] r
               ON r.currency_id = u.balance_currency
       LEFT JOIN [db].[order] o
              ON o.user_id = u.id
                 AND o.status = 'shipped'
       LEFT JOIN address_pivot ap
              ON ap.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP  BY u.id,
          u.date_created,
          u.NAME,
          u.password,
          u.email,
          r.token,
          u.balance,
          address_1,
          city_1,
          state_1,
          address_2,
          city_2,
          state_2,
          Address_count
ORDER  BY TotalShippedOrders DESC;
```

Comment: Why the `Max` in the pivot?

Comment: @VR46 This is awesome! I'll google pivoting to figure out the logic behind your code. How can I add another column that has total number of addresses per user?

Comment: @xMetalDetectorx - updated the answer to get the total count of address per user

Comment: @MotoGP - i appreciate that! But it looks like it's only giving a max count of 2 and not the total number of addresses per user

Comment: @xMetalDetectorx - I have removed the where condition here `FROM   address_cte
         GROUP  BY user_id)`. Please execute the above query and check

Comment: @xMetalDetectorx - You can mark it as answer if this helped you

Answer (score 0):

dig into **outer apply**:

```
;with [Users] as
(
  select 1 as id, 'jim' as name
  union all
  select 2, 'jane'
),
[Address] as
(
  select 1 as id, 1 as user_id, 'new york' as addr
  union all
  select 2, 2, 'tokio'
  union all
  select 3, 2, 'moscow'
  union all
  select 4, 2, 'paris'
  union all
  select 5, 2, 'london'
  union all
  select 6, 2, 'canberra'
)
select u.*, a.addr
from [Users] u
outer apply
(
  select
    stuff(cast((
      select top 2
        ', ' + a.addr 
      from [Address] a
      where a.user_id = u.id
      order by a.id desc
      for xml path('')
     ) as varchar(8000)), 1, 2, '') as addr
) a
```

`top 2` and concatenation